# Nested Dictionary objects json serialization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework to returned response in json format for jquery.
I have a dictionary object which contains another dictionary object:

```
items = {
         ['name':'Chairs','options':{'type':'office','price':100}],
         ['name':'Tables','options':{'type':'office','price':45}],
}

response = Response( json.dumps(output_items) , status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

On JavaScript side I am using this code:

```
var array = JSON.parse(json);
```

that is not parsing JSON, that is creating errors.

I want to create this json format:

```
    {
                "1": {
                    "name": "Chairs",
                    "description": "All chairs",
                    "options": {
                        "1":{"type": "Office", "price": 130 },
                        "2":{"type": "Home", "price": 75 },
                        "3":{"type": "Shop", "price": 100 }
                    }
                },
                "2": {
                    "name": "Tables",
                    "description": "table description",
                    "options": {
                        "1":{"type": "Office", "price": 240 },
                        "2":{"type": "Home", "price": 200 },
                        "3":{"type": "Shop", "price": 180 }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I stored all my data using python dictionary and list objects , how can i create this format json output string from dictionaries data?

Comment: What does the error say? BTW , `['name':'Chairs','options':{'type':'office','price':100}]` ... are you sure this is a proper JSON or even a proper python object definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a proper json or Python object. Python Lists cannot take named arguments. Only a dictionary can take key, value pairs. If you wish to go for a list, it has to be dictionaries added to the list and not as key value pairs. The items should be something like this:

List of dictionaries

```
items = [
     {"name":"Chairs","options":{"type":"office","price":100}},
     {"name":"Tables","options":{"type":"office","price":45}},
]
```

(or)
Dictionary of dictionaries

```
items = {
      "first":{"name":"Chairs","options":{"type":"office","price":100}},
      "second":{"name":"Tables","options":{"type":"office","price":45}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in you object "items". Try this one

```
items = [
         {'name':'Chairs','options':{'type':'office','price':100}},
         {'name':'Tables','options':{'type':'office','price':45}},
]
```

You have an error in dict creation `['name':'Chairs','options':{'type':'office','price':100}]` This is not a pair of key: value

Answer (score 0):

you are not doing it correctly as mentioned by others, you can test it in your  browser's console just type in

```
x={'type':'office','price':100}
//Object {type: "office", price: 100}
y={'type':'office','price':45}
//Object {type: "office", price: 45}
opt1={'type':x}
//Object {type: Object}
opt2={'type':y}
//Object {type: Object}
val1={'name':'Chairs', 'options':opt1}
//Object {name: "Chairs", options: Object}
val2={name:'tables','options':opt2}
//Object {name: "tables", options: Object}
items={'1':val1,'2':val2}
```

you will have the needed format for your data and you will get an idea about how to formulate the data too. hope it helps